# Why the Bootstrap.esm.js error when using Bootstrap 5 with VueJS 2?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Bootstrap 5 and my [drop downs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/) stopped working.  I checked my npm updates and didn't see anything out of the ordinary. I even emulated my setup on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-robinson-5mpkz?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) and it works fine there, just not on my machine.

However, I do see a console error on my local machine that says:

```
bootstrap.esm.js?7b17:3131 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hide')
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (bootstrap.esm.js?7b17:3131)
    at HTMLDocument.handler (bootstrap.esm.js?7b17:387)
eval @ bootstrap.esm.js?7b17:3131
handler @ bootstrap.esm.js?7b17:387
```

Here's template for drop down code (took it straight out of Bootstrap 5 docs) in a VueJS template:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button
        class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        id="dropdownMenuButton1"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown'
export default {
}
</script>
```

Anyone spot any issues and reasons for the error on my machine?

Updated with package.json info:

```
{
  "name": "XXX,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.6.1",
    "core-js": "^3.17.2",
    "jso-2": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-select": "^3.13.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Share your package.json on machine

Comment: @VitaliyRayets: Added package.json. Sorry forgot to do that in the first place!

Comment: Strange, all is correct. Try to delete `node_modules` and then install again

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting node modules did not work. Any ideas for next step? I post on bootstrap github issues page maybe?